# String.match() with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am having trouble with some code I am using to validate a string. Every letter in the string must be surrounded by a '+' symbol to pass, in which case the validation function should return true. To do this, I am using String.match() with a regex to identify any illegal patterns, and return true if the match returns a null value (i.e. no illegal patterns are found).

My regular expression seems to work when I test it on a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/rE4hF0/1) however, the match fails when testing it on something like jsbin. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and/or whether there is a better way I should be testing this?

```
/* Using the JavaScript language, have the function SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable        sequence by either returning the string true or false. The str parameter  will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters between them (ie.++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be     surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The     string will not be empty and will have at least one letter. 
*/

function SimpleSymbols(str){
  // search for illegal patterns (i.e. ^+[a-z]+ or +[a-z]^+)
  var illegalPatterns = str.match( /[^+][a-z][+]|[+][a-z][^+]/ig );
  // return true if no illegal patterns are found
    return illegalPatterns === null;
}

console.log(SimpleSymbols("++a+d+"));    // expect true       
console.log(SimpleSymbols("+a+a"));  // expect false
console.log(SimpleSymbols("+a++++a+"));  // expect true
console.log(SimpleSymbols("+a++++aa+"));  // expect false
```

Comment: please include where it fails..

Comment: Hi @karthik, here is a link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jujimahido/1/) with the test cases

Comment: `+a+a` why are you expecting true here... your regex will match this because last `a` is not surrounded by `+`...

Comment: I'm not expecting true for that test....+a+a should return false

Comment: change your regex to `[a-z]{2}` and return false for matches..

Comment: [a-z]{2} will only catch cases where there are multiple letters in a row; however, I really want to test for any letter which is NOT directly preceded or followed by a '+'

Comment: you mean the letter should not be at start and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this matches, the test *passed*

```
 # ^\++(?:[a-zA-Z]\++)+$

 ^ 
 \++
 (?: [a-zA-Z] \++ )+
 $
```

**edit**
The above allowed characters are alpha and plus.
So, it appears you want to have any characters, but 
only the alpha's must be surrounded by plus.

That is much more complicated.
That situation is handled by the below regex.
When this matches, *NO* flaw is found.

```
 # ^(?:[^a-zA-Z+]+|(?:(?:\++[a-zA-Z](?=\+))*|\++))*$

 ^                    # BOS
 (?:                  # 0 to many of either non-apha's or alphas surrounded by plus
      [^a-zA-Z+]+          # 1 to many, Not alpha nor plus
   |                     # or,
      (?:
           (?:                  # 0 to many, plus alpha
                \++
                [a-zA-Z]             # Single alpha
                (?= \+ )             # Assert, plus ahead
           )*
        |                     # or,
           \++                  # 1 to many plus
      )
 )*
 $                    # EOS
```

**edit**
And I guess you could do the previous regex like this..
But, when this matches, a flaw *WAS* found.

```
 # (?:^|[^+])[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?!\+)

    (?: ^ | [^+] )
    [a-zA-Z] 
 |  
    [a-zA-Z] 
    (?! \+ )
```

Comment: close, but wouldn't this fail if there are no alpha characters, such as "+++"? The only reason the test should not pass is if there are alphas that are not surrounded by '+' symbols.

Comment: @capolo2 - Ok, adjusted it to include any character, making it more complex. You have to be more specific with these details. As it is now, it only fails if an alpha is not surrounded by plus. Everything else passes.

Comment: Thanks, @sln. So in situations like this wouldn't it be much easier to just test for the invalid patterns and return true if the match for invalid patterns returns null?

Comment: @capolo2 - I added a last pattern that distills it into just that. Yes, but what you have to realize is that sometimes defining a invalid pattern requires defining a partial validity to compare it with. Also, JS has regex issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Your regex searches for `(anything other than +)(letter)(+)` or `(+)(letter)(anything other than +)`

`+a+a` will be matched because end of the string is `(anything other than +)` and `+a` is a match.

You can use the following instead:

```
[a-z]{2}|^[a-z]|[a-z]$          //check if two characters are not 
                                //separated by `+` and return false
```

Comment: that would fail to match in the case of a string such as "a"

Comment: also.. why is `a` valid and `+a+a` invalid?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Karthik. They are both invalid. When I said 'a' should match, I don't mean that it is valid. I am matching for the illegal patterns, so 'a' should match, as should 'a+a+', and both are invalid

Comment: @capolo2 check the update..if it gives a match.. string is invalid.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
^[a-z][+]|[^+][a-z][+]|[+][a-z][^+]|[+][a-z]$
```

I added more cases to your RegEx and woked. I am testing **boundary** cases too

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rE4hF0/2)

```js
function SimpleSymbols(str){
  var illegalPatterns = str.match(/^[a-z][+]|[^+][a-z][+]|[+][a-z][^+]|[+][a-z]$/ig);
  // return true if no illegal patterns are found
    return illegalPatterns === null;
}


var result = ""
result += SimpleSymbols("++a+d+") + "\n";    // expect true       
result += SimpleSymbols("+a+a") + "\n";  // expect false
result += SimpleSymbols("+a++++a+") + "\n";  // expect true
result += SimpleSymbols("+a++++aa+") + "\n";  // expect false

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

---

But I prefer to test the **valid** ones like:

```
(?:\++[a-zA-Z]\++)+[a-zA-Z]\++
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for matching your valid string:

```
/^\+*(?:\++[a-zA-Z](?=\+))*\+*$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF4xT7/2)

---

**EDIT:** To detect invalid matches you can also use:

```
/[^+][a-z](?=\+)|\+[a-z](?!\+)/gi
```

Comment: He claims to not be testing for a valid string, only for an invalid string.

Comment: Call `test` on this regex and check for false